# How can I generate a cSYM from release build output that contains correct symbols?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

For Android, I have a native project that I am integrating firebaseCrashlytics with.

When I force a crash, it appears in the console. However, I can not get symbolication to occur. The output from my build process are in `build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj`, and these appear to be used correctly to generate symbols to upload to firebase using the gradle task successfully.

`app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease`

```
22:08:02.617 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Generating native symbol files for libs in: android/project/crash_reporting/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj; writing output symbols to: android/project/crash_reporting/build/crashlytics/Release/nativeSymbols
22:08:02.617 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Crashlytics generating cSYM files from object files in android/project/crash_reporting/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj:
22:08:02.937 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Generating symbols for android/project/crash_reporting/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi-v7a/libcrash_reporting.so
22:08:02.938 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Using DWARF data for cSYM generation.
22:08:03.711 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Generating symbols for android/project/crash_reporting/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86/libcrash_reporting.so
22:08:03.712 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Using DWARF data for cSYM generation.
22:08:04.525 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Generating symbols for android/project/crash_reporting/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a/libcrash_reporting.so
22:08:04.525 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Using DWARF data for cSYM generation.
```

Looking into the `*.so` file, I can see the symbols for the method that is raising the exception. I can also see in the console that it *attempts* to symbolicate, but gets it wrong.

When I manually generate the `.cSYM` file and look at it in android studio, i don't see the method names I'm expecting.

If I generate a `cSYM` with the debug `*.so` output, I do see the method names i'm expected.

If I enable crashlytics for debug, and upload those symbols, I can symbolicate my debug builds. I cannot do the same for release builds. Is there something that needs to be done to either

(1) generate cSYM for release with enough information? some DWARF flag?
(2) use the cSYM generated from a debug output to be used by release builds.

Edit:
Or ... do I simply need to build release build with debuggable set to true, generate and upload the symbols, and then do nothing with the build. It was just for symbol generation. Is that a typical approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here -

If you're seeing that crashes are getting properly symbolicated on debug but not release, it may have to do with specific build settings you've enabled. Are you building your native libraries any differently when you're building for your release apps? Is your Gradle build any different when you build for your release apps?

It can be useful to go into debug mode and observe the logcat once you've invoked `app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease`. If you're doing both `debug` and `release`, I recommend invoking both of those tasks with --debug and saving the logs that are output. There can be a lot of output that's unrelated, so you may want to attach a filter to the invocation:

`./gradlew ... | grep "[com.google.firebase.crashlytics]"`

And then observing if you notice any differences between these logs. You may also want to make sure you're cleaning the build between uploads and different build types here. Things to look out for in the logs: 
-DWARF is still being used to generate cSYMs in both cases
-the paths for your stripped and unstripped symbols remaining the same between debug and release

Otherwise, this seems like a strange issue you're running into and you may want support to dig into your setup a little more than we can do on a public forum. If so, you may want to reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) with the details you've gathered, and they should have some troubleshooting suggestions specific to your setup.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

For debug builds, I set `debuggable=true` which obviously generates a much larger output *.so to generate symbols from. For release, this is not set. The shared object is much smaller, but if I examine it I can still see human readable method names. When I generate a cSYM from this file, it's not present. The logs indicate DWARF data is being used here.

When building a release build with the intent of running the task to generate and upload symbols, do they need to be built in a specific way? in earlier NDK build configurations, we use to use NDK_DEBUG.

Comment: I guess more specifically, how do I ensure my release build `*.so` ndk project builds with DWARF data so it can be used to generate a correct cSYM.

Comment: I think there's some overloaded terminology here. When you say "debug" are you talking about the buildTypes in your Gradle file, or are you referring to the "unstripped" version of your binary? From the OP it sounds like you get good symbolication when you generate symbols based on the "debug" (I'm assuming "unstripped") version of your .so files - this would be expected, as it has the correct info we need to generate useful symbol mappings.

Comment: I would say that to answer these questions we'd need more in depth info on how you set up your build - ndkbuild, cmake, etc - as well as how the libraries are built (separate from the Android app, or as a part of it?) You may want to reach out to Firebase support with that - I will probably see the case :)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I have submitted a support ticket with additional information.